# Ruby TempFile behaviour among different classes

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection, temporary-files

Our processing server works mainly with TempFiles as it makes things easier on our side: no need to take care of deleting them as they get garbage collected or handle name collisions, etc.

Lately, we are having problems with TempFiles getting GCed too early in the process. Specially with one of our services that will convert a `Foo` file from a url to some `Bar` file and upload it to our servers.

For sake of clarity I added bellow a case scenario in order to make discussion easier and have an example at hand.

This workflow does the following:

1. Get a url as parameter
2. Download the Foo file as a TempFile
3. Duplicate it to a new TempFile
4. Download the related assets to TempFiles
5. Link the related assets into the local dup TempFile
6. Convert the Foo to Bar format
7. Upload it to our server

At times the conversion fail and everything points to the fact that our local Foo file is pointing to related assets that have been created and GCed before the conversion.

My two questions:

1. Is it possible that my TempFiles get GCed too early? I read about Ruby GCed system it was very conservative to avoid those scenarios.
2. How can I avoid this from happening? I could try to save all related assets from `download_and_replace_uri(node)` and passing them as a return to keep it alive while the instance of `ConvertService` is still existing. But I'm not sure if this would solve it.

**myfile.foo**

```
{
  "buffers": [
    { "uri": "http://example.com/any_file.jpg" },
    { "uri": "http://example.com/any_file.png" },
    { "uri": "http://example.com/any_file.jpmp3" }
  ]
}
```

**main.rb**

```rb
  ConvertService.new('http://example.com/myfile.foo')
```

**ConvertService**

```rb
class ConvertService
  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
    @bar_file = Tempfile.new
  end

  def call
    import_foo
    convert_foo
    upload_bar
  end

  private

  def import_foo
    @foo_file = ImportService.new(@url).call.edited_file
  end

  def convert_foo
    `create-bar "#{@foo_file.path}" "#{@bar_file.path}"`
  end

  def upload_bar
    UploadBarService.new(@bar_file).call
  end
end
```

**ImportService**

```rb
class ImportService
  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
    @edited_file ||= Tempfile.new
  end

  def call
    download
    duplicate
    replace
  end

  private

  def download
    @original = DownloadFileService.new(@url).call.file
  end

  def duplicate
    FileUtils.cp(@original.path, @edited_file.path)
  end

  def replace
    file = File.read(@edited_file.path)
    json = JSON.parse(file, symbolize_names: true)
    json[:buffers]&.each do |node| 
      node[:uri] = DownloadFileService.new(node[:uri]).call.file.path
    end
    write_to_disk(@edited_file.path, json.to_json)
  end
end
```

**DownloadFileService**

```rb
module Helper
  class DownloadFileService < ApplicationHelperService
    def initialize(url)
      @url = url
      @file = Tempfile.new
    end

    def call
      uri = URI.parse(@url)
      Net::HTTP.start(
        uri.host, 
        uri.port, 
        use_ssl: uri.scheme == 'https'
      ) do |http|
        response = http.request(Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path))
        @file.binmode
        @file.write(response.body)
        @file.flush
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**UploadBarService**

```rb
module Helper
  class UploadBarService < ApplicationHelperService
    def initialize(file)
      @file = file
    end

    def call
      HTTParty.post('http://example.com/upload', body: { file: @file })
      # NOTE: End points returns the url for the uploaded file
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read [mre]. You've essentially uploaded your entire app here and want someone to parse it and figure it out for you. You're far more likely to get help by doing some work yourself to reduce this down substantially. The code you've provided can't even be run by anyone as it's missing parts like `ApplicationHelperService`, and even if that were present it STILL wouldn't be usable because it depends on other data we don't have.

Comment: Perhaps [this discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/ewm3mk/working_with_tempfiles/) might be helpful?

Comment: @anothermh The goal of the code was to give people some idea of the structure. This is not really possible to give something working out of the box as (if you would have looked at the message) will require to set an upload server and other mechanics that are out of the ruby scope and the way TempFile works...

Comment: @lacostenycoder Awesome link! and the link it leads to says even more (in short). TempFiles are GCed if no running code points to it. The code in `ImportService#replace` gets TempFiles via `DownloadFileService` and uses its path without keeping in memory the reference to it. So when this instance gets GCed, the reference to the TempFile (even if still used on other TempFiles) are destroyed. To avoid this, a global adding a class array in `ImportService` and appending the TempFile instance to it should be enough as my `ImportService` will live until the end of `ConvertService`

Comment: The link in question https://www.hilman.io/blog/2016/01/tempfile/

Answer (score 0):

Because of the complexity of your code and missing parts which may be obfuscated to us, the simple answer to your problem is to insure that your tempfile instance objects remain in memory throughout the lifecycle in which they are needed, otherwise they will get garbage collected immediately, removing the tempfile from the file system, and will lead to the the missing tempfile state you've encountered.

The [Ruby Document for Tempfile states](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) "When a Tempfile object is garbage collected, or when the Ruby interpreter exits, its associated temporary file is automatically deleted."

As per comments, others may find [this conversation](https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/ewm3mk/working_with_tempfiles/) helpful when running into this problem.