# Tempfile in Ruby deleted before garbage collection

Tags: ruby, temporary-files

I have code like:

```
      json_file = Tempfile.new("json_cred_")
      json_file.write(auth_json)
      json_file.close
      return GCE.new(:json_cred => json_file.path, :auth_type => "json",
                     :avoid_garbage_collection => json_file)
```

Inside `GCE` class methods there is code like:

```
        if !File.exist?(config[:json_cred])
          logger.error "Tempfile deleted: #{config[:avoid_garbage_collection]&.inspect}"
          raise
        end
```

Later during execution some 40% of the times the above fails. And the logged error is the expected:

```
[17:10:44] ERROR> Tempfile deleted: #<Tempfile:/home/jenkins/workspace/Runner-v3/workdir/json_cred_20200801-375-hqhu72 (closed)>
```

Any idea how it is possible that the tempfile becomes missing? Except for some external process deleting it, I see no other way. But also I don't see any such external process as this is a container based CI system and only the test process is running inside it. So I'm asking if there might be any other explanation that I'm missing.

This is with `ruby 2.6.2p47 (2019-03-13 revision 67232) [x86_64-linux]`.

Comment: I recommend the comments at https://stackoverflow.com/q/62950100/3784008 as someone recently made a similar post with a bounty, but found the answer to their troubles in the comments.